# Decorator for children of abstract generic Container class in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-decorator, typescript2.6

I'm having trouble with Typescript generics. **I'm using Typescript 2.6**.

The basic idea is that I want to create a MobX store that exposes a class decorator adding basic authentication check, and that decorator takes a class type derived from the abstract generic `Container` class (a React Router route container, for example).

Here is the code leading to the issue:

```
interface Newable<T, U = any> {
  new (...args: U[]): T;
}

function withAuth<TContainer extends Container<TProps, TState>, TProps extends Container.Props, TState>(ctor: Newable<TContainer>): Newable<TContainer> {
  return class WithAuth extends ctor {
    public async componentWillMount() {
      await this.props.stores.authentication.tryLoggingIn();
      super.componentWillMount();
    }

    public async componentWillUpdate() {
      await this.props.stores.authentication.tryLoggingIn();
      super.componentWillUpdate();
    }

    public render(): React.ReactNode {
      return super.render();
    }
  };
}
```

Both the `TProps` and `TState` generic parameters can be redefined by the derived class, as they may have more React props or a complex state.

---

The error messages I get from the Typescript compiler:

```
Type 'typeof WithAuth' is not assignable to type 'Newable<TContainer, any>'. Type 'WithAuth' is not assignable to type 'TContainer'. (line 6)
Base constructor return type 'TContainer' is not a class or interface type. (line 6)
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'WithAuth'. (line 8)
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'WithAuth'. (line 14)
```

Removing the return type of the withAuth function leads to this error:

```
Base constructor return type 'TContainer' is not a class or interface type.
```

---

Here is the relevant code for the `Container` class (simplified, it contains a little bit more stuff):

```
abstract class Container<T extends Container.Props = Container.Props, U extends React.ComponentState = {}> extends React.Component<T, U> {
  public abstract render(): React.ReactNode;
}

namespace Container {
  export type Props = React.Props<any>; // TODO: typings
}
```

---

What I don't get is, even using a non-generic class instead of Container leads to the

```
Base constructor return type 'TContainer' is not a class or interface type.
```

error. However, as you can see in the generic parameter declaration, TContainer IS DERIVED from a class. From what I get, this shouldn't be an issue.

So my question is, **how can I create a class decorator to the `Container<TProps, TState>` that would add authentication checks to `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate`?**

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use mixins, which are described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743). The way it works is pretty particular, the class that will be augmented must be passed in as a type parameter, which can be constrained to extend the abstract class. Note that since we mandate the class will have a callable constructor, the class passed to  `withAuth` can't be `Container` but rather a class that is derived from `Container` and implements the abstract methods already.

```
abstract class Container<T extends Container.Props = Container.Props, U extends React.ComponentState = {}> extends React.Component<T, U> {
    public abstract render(): React.ReactNode;
}

namespace Container {
    export type Props = {
        stores: any
    };
}

interface Newable<T, U = any> {
    new(...args: U[]): T;
}

function withAuth<TCtor extends Newable<Container<Container.Props, any>>>(ctor: TCtor) {
    return class WithAuth extends ctor {
        public async componentWillMount() {
            await this.props.stores.authentication.tryLoggingIn();
            this.componentWillMount();
        }

        public async componentWillUpdate() {
            await this.props.stores.authentication.tryLoggingIn();
            this.componentWillUpdate();
        }

        public render(): React.ReactNode {
            return this.render();
        }
    };
}

class NewComponent extends Container< Container.Props & { otherProp: string}, any> {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        // Actual implementation 
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }

}
const NewComponentWitAuth = withAuth(NewComponent);

let witAuth = <NewComponentWitAuth otherProp="" stores={null}  /> // props type is preserved
```

Comment: Oh alright, that makes sense! Thanks a bunch for the link!